# Trying to get recommended books from list unable to build correct logic

Tags: flutter, dart

*Here is method in dart with books as a List need to check based on boolean value if its recomended
assign that books to recommended[i] list.* Need to make correct logic for it in dart. Please help THank you.

```
void recommendedBooksLists(RxList<dynamic> books) {
    if (books.recommended==true){
// if books are recommended assign those books something like recommeded.assign(book)
    }
```

Comment: Inside the function, first remove the if block. Then write a loop to go through each element in `books` array and check whether each book is recommended. If yes, push those books to another list. After going through all books, return that new list.

Answer (score 2):

you have to loop through the values of the books and push the book which is recommended as example

```
void recommendedBooksLists(RxList<dynamic> books) {
    recommended = [];
    for(var book in books.value){
        if(book['recommended'] as bool == true){
            recommended.add(book);
        }
    }
}
```